# Split String in Javascript with a given format

Tags: javascript

I have string `"club160"`, but I want to get string `"club-160"`, how I can do this? I need to use `split()` func? For split I need delimiter but there is no comma, or space.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How is this split or explode?

Comment: More detail, please. Always four letters followed by three digits? Always needs a dash after the last letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a regular expression and a replace operation:

```
var s = "club160"
var result = s.replace(/([a-z])([0-9])/i, '$1-$2')
```

But this only replaces something like `aaa111` to `aaa-111`, `111aaa` will stay `111aaa`

Answer (score 1):

If the string always contains at least one digit or letter, consider:

```
var s = 'club160';
s.match(/(\d+)|([a-z]+)/ig).join('-'); // club-160

var t = '160club';
t.match(/(\d+)|([a-z]+)/ig).join('-'); // 160-club
```

It doesn't care about order or how many groups of letters and numbers are present. However, it requires at least one letter or number in the string, otherwise it will throw an error.

As a function, dealing with errors:

```
function specialSplit(s) {

  // Make sure string has at least one letter or digit
  if (/\d|[a-z]/i.test(s)) {
    return s.match(/(\d+)|([a-z]+)/ig).join('-');
  }
  // Otherwise return undefined
}
```